# Installation exits before I can press Y to continue when installing nodejs

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, nodejs

Im a new Ubuntu/Linux user and im having a bit of trouble installing nodejs. I tried installing it using `sudo apt install nodejs` and it returned this:

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk python2.7-doc binutils binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib nodejs python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 31.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 144 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
username@server:/$
```

It looks like it aborted before I had the chance to press Y. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you do but alternatively you could use `sudo apt-get -y install nodejs`.  This is equivalent to answer Yes.  I am surprised that nodejs requires Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Try the -y option.

```
sudo apt install nodejs -y
```